# Is this implementation of the Hindley-Milner algorithm correct?

Tags: c#

I based this implementation upon the implementation given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16215688/1219414) and the book linked in it, but modified it to, instead of a constraint list and a substitution stack, generate a substitution tree in a single tree traversal operation.

Each node in the substitution tree is a `VariableType`. Child nodes are in the `Types` array. Types with no children represent just variable types, types with one child represent type that have been replaced with the child, and types with two children represent function types.

The `Deepest` method gets the current substitute given any type, since to replace, say, `a` with `b`, provided `a` is a leaf (has no children), you just set `b` to be the only child of `a`. This is what the `ReplaceWith` method does, which must take a leaf as the type to be replaced.

The `Unify` method must always get deepest terms (terms with zero or two children).

```
public interface ILambdaTerm { }

public interface IVariableTerm : ILambdaTerm
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IAbstractionTerm : ILambdaTerm
{
    string ArgumentName { get; }
    ILambdaTerm Body { get; }
}

public interface IApplicationTerm : ILambdaTerm
{
    ILambdaTerm Function { get; }
    ILambdaTerm[] Parameters { get; }
}

public class VariableType
{
    public VariableType[] Types;

    public VariableType(VariableType argType, VariableType resType)
    {
        Types = new VariableType[] { argType, resType };
    }

    public VariableType() 
    {
        Types = new VariableType[0];
    }

    private bool Contains(VariableType type)
    {
        if (Types.Length == 0)
            return this == type;
        else
            return Types.Any(subType => subType.Contains(type));
    }

    public void ReplaceWith(VariableType type)
    {
        if (type.Contains(this))
            throw new Exception("Circular type.");
        Types = new VariableType[] { type };
    }

    public VariableType Deepest()
    {
        VariableType type = this;
        while (type.Types.Length == 1)
            type = type.Types[0];
        return type;
    }
}

public class TypeChecking
{
    private static void Unify(VariableType a, VariableType b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return;

        if (a.Types.Length == 0)
            a.ReplaceWith(b);
        else
        {
            if (b.Types.Length == 0)
                b.ReplaceWith(a);
            else
            {
                Unify(a.Types[0].Deepest(), b.Types[0].Deepest());
                Unify(a.Types[1].Deepest(), b.Types[1].Deepest());
            }
        }
    }

    private static VariableType TypeOfTerm(ILambdaTerm term, IScope<VariableType> typeContext)
    {
        if (term is IVariableTerm)
        {
            var varTerm = (IVariableTerm)term;
            if (!typeContext.ContainsKey(varTerm.Name))
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Undeclared variable '{0}'.", varTerm.Name));
            return typeContext[varTerm.Name].Deepest();
        }
        if (term is IAbstractionTerm)
        {
            var absTerm = (IAbstractionTerm)term;
            var argType = new VariableType();
            var resType = TypeOfTerm(absTerm.Body, new InnerScope<VariableType>(typeContext, absTerm.ArgumentName, argType));
            return new VariableType(argType, resType);
        }
        if (term is IApplicationTerm)
        {
            var appTerm = (IApplicationTerm)term;
            var resType = new VariableType();
            var argType = TypeOfTerm(appTerm.Parameters[0], typeContext);
            var funType = TypeOfTerm(appTerm.Function, typeContext);
            Unify(funType, new VariableType(argType, resType));
            return resType.Deepest();
        }
        else
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Dunno what to do with a '{0}'.", term));
    }

    public static VariableType TypeOfTerm(ILambdaTerm term)
    {
        return TypeOfTerm(term, new GlobalScope<VariableType>());
    }
}
```

I also have an extension method which returns a type as a string, that uses a `Dictionary<VariableType, string>` to automatically assign a name to each type, considering only deepest types (types with zero or two children). I'm not to worried about this method so I skipped it to keep the post short.

I'm not too worried about performance as I'm about correctness of the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say much about the correctness but I have some comments about the design:

1. Whenever you write code like this:

   ```
   if (foo is SomeType)
   {
      // do something
   }
   else if (foo is SomeOtherType)
   {
      // do something else
   }
   ...
   ```

   then this is an indicator that your abstraction is flawed. I'm not saying you should never ever do it but more often than not it indicates a design problem.
2. Another point is the empty `ILambdaTerm` interface. An interface is like a contract - so what does an empty contract mean? Not much really.
3. Don't throw generic `Exception`. In your case an `InvalidOperationException` or maybe your own defined `TermValidationException` would probably make more sense. This would give the user at least some way of catching specific exceptions.

---

For the design here is what I would consider changing:

1. Move `Unify` into `VariableType` and make it public. `Unify` only operates on `VariableType`s so it makes more sense to live on the `VariableType` class.
2. `Types` in `VariableType` can now become private as well which reduces unnecessary exposure of the internal data storage of the class.
3. Add a method `VariableType GetVariableType(IScope<VariableType> typeContext)` to the `ILambdaTerm` interface and move the implementation of the logic from the `if (term is ...)` blocks into the `GetVariableType` implementation in each of the concrete classes for the terms, e.g.:

   ```
   public interface VariableTerm : IVariableTerm 
   {
       public string Name { get; private set; }

       public VariableTerm(string name)
       {
           Name = name;
       }

       public override VariableType GetVariableType(IScope<VariableType> typeContext)
       {
           if (!typeContext.ContainsKey(Name))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Undeclared variable '{0}'.", Name));
           return typeContext[Name].Deepest();
       }
   }
   ```

   Now you can get the `VariableType` of a term simply by writing:

   ```
   ILambdaTerm myTerm = ...
   ...

   var variableType = term.GetVariableType(new GlobalScope<VariableType>());
   ```

   and your `TypeChecking` class can disappear.